# ListPlot with joined line

Tags: plotting

I have a plot that I would like to make it like a ListPlot with joined lines. I mean, for each integer ‘k’, I want to have a dot over each line.

Here is the simplified plot:

```
γ = 50;
F[n_] := 1 + n (23 γ) + 154;

Ftotal[n_, k_] := k F[n] + (27);
Plot[{Ftotal[500, k], Ftotal[300, k]}, {k, 7, 12}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the `Mesh` option of `Plot[]`?

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties Thanks you

Answer (score 4):

```
Show[
 Plot[{Ftotal[500, k], Ftotal[300, k]}, {k, 7, 12},
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[Transpose@Table[{{k, Ftotal[500, k]},
     {k, Ftotal[300, k]}}, {k, 7, 12}]]]
```

[image: Output]

or since the lines are straight

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[{{k, Ftotal[500, k]},
    {k, Ftotal[300, k]}}, {k, 7, 12}],
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{0, 0}]}],
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

> Same output.

Also, plot with epilog

```
Plot[{Ftotal[500, k], Ftotal[300, k]}, {k, 7, 12},
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015],
   Transpose@Prepend[Map[Point, Table[
       {{k, Ftotal[500, k]}, {k, Ftotal[300, k]}}, {k, 7, 12}], {2}],
     {ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 2]}]}]
```

> Same output.

and as J. M.'s technical difficulties observes, use of `Mesh`

```
Plot[{Ftotal[500, k], Ftotal[300, k]}, {k, 7, 12},
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,
 Mesh -> {Range[7, 12]}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image: Output]

but in this instance the end points are not plotted.

It works with the `ListLinePlot` version though.

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[{{k, Ftotal[500, k]},
    {k, Ftotal[300, k]}}, {k, 7, 12}],
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you @chris

Comment: Chris, why do you make it a point to specify “since the lines are straight” before you give a method using `ListLinePlot`?

Comment: Hi. Because in plotting the integer results from Table any curve between the points would not be plotted.  See this example : `ListLinePlot[Transpose @ Table[{{k^16, Ftotal[500, k]}, {k^16, Ftotal[300, k]}}, {k, 4, 7}], PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{0, 0}]}], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]`